# Insert div as the .lastElementChild without 'insertBefore' without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, child-nodes, parent-node

Okay so I've usually had **.box-4** as the last element inside of **.s1** as shown below:

```
<div class="s1">
 <div class="box-1"></div>
 <div class="box-2"></div>
 <div class="box-3"></div>
 <div class="box-4"></div>
</div>
```

and had **.box-1** move before **.box-4** using the JavaScript:

```
var box1 = document.querySelector('.box-1');
var s1 = box1.parentNode;

s1.insertBefore(box1, s1.lastElementChild);
```

to receive the following outcome:

```
<div class="s1">
 <div class="box-2"></div>
 <div class="box-3"></div>
 <div class="box-1"></div>
 <div class="box-4"></div>
</div>
```

however, I have recently removed **.box-4** from **.s1**, and consequently **.box-1** no longer move/becomes **the** **.lastElementChild.** I would still like **.box-1** to move, and hence become last, however, I'm unsure of what command will achieve this; desirably something like this

```
.insertAs(box1, s1.lastElementChild);
```

to achieve this:

```
<div class="s1">
 <div class="box-2"></div>
 <div class="box-3"></div>
 <div class="box-1"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE: **.box-1** changes position depending on screen-width, so simply moving the div in HTML is not an option.

NOTE: **Vanilla JavaScript only** - No jQquery.

Thanks in advance guys, much appreciated!

Comment: This can be done without script. Would that be an option? 
 https://jsfiddle.net/vq2ngksw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will append box1 as the last child (automatically removes it from it's original position).

```
var box1 = document.querySelector('.box-1');
var s1 = box1.parentNode;

s1.appendChild(box1);
```

Comment: Thanks friend! Worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To insert HTML without jQuery simply use insertAdjactedHTML function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.appendChild`?

```js
const box1 = document.querySelector('.box-1');
const s1 = box1.parentElement;
box1.remove();
s1.appendChild(box1);
```

```html
<div class="s1">
 <div class="box-1">b1</div>
 <div class="box-2">b2</div>
 <div class="box-3">b3</div>
 <div class="box-4">b4</div>
</div>
```